# Alternative for "all for one, one for all"

Tags: word-choice, phrase-requests, idiom-requests

Looking for an alternative idiom/phrase, etc. for the titular term. Any idea?

Comment: Maybe *Interdependence* will work.

Answer (score 3):

"Solidarity" springs to mind.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Solidarity

See also the Zulu word "Ubuntu" which has several meanings, one of which is "the bond of sharing".  It has a free operating system named after it.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ubuntu_(philosophy)

Answer (score 1):

Consider the Belgium motto "l'union fait la force" whose translations are:

- **"there is strength in unity"**,
- or, "together we are stronger".